# Failing to redirect after sign up

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, routes, fetch

So I am redirecting after a user has signed up and I wanting to redirect them to the home page. This is how my code looks starting with the auth controller

```
const handleErrors = (err) => {
    console.log(err.message, err.code);
    const errors = {email: "", password: ""};

// duplicate error code
if(err.code === 11000) {
    errors.email = "This email is already in use";
    return errors;}


// validation errors
if(err.message.includes("user validation failed")) {
    Object.values(err.errors).forEach(({properties}) => {
        errors[properties.path] = properties.message;
    })
};
return errors
}

const maxAge = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60;
const createToken = (id) => {
    return jwt.sign({id}, "private key", {expiresIn: maxAge})
}


module.exports.signup_post = async (req, res) => {
const {email, password} = req.body;

try {
    const user = await User.create({email, password});
    const token = createToken(user._id);
    res.cookie("jwt", token, {httpOnly: true, maxAge: maxAge * 1000})
    res.status(201).json({user: user._id});
} catch (err) {
    const errors = handleErrors(err);
    res.status(400).json({ errors });
}

}
```

Then this is the signup route script code

```
try {
  const res = await fetch("/signup", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({email, password}),
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
  });
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);

  if(data.errors){
    emailError.textContent = data.errors.email;
    passwordError.textContent = data.errors.password;
  };

  if(data.users){
    res.redirect("/");
    // location.assign("/");
  }
```

I have tried both redirect and location assign but none of them are working. What could be the problem?

Comment: The `res` you are taking is not a response instance. It won't redirect. You need to use the actual response object coming into the application. Can you share more code?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara i have update my post added more code

Comment: add signup handler, you must be passing res, req to it. Use that request object and it will redirect safely.

Answer (score 0):

If this is client side, try `window.location.replace`

```
window.location.replace('http://host:port/login');
```